# Authenticate On LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api

I created two app on Linkedin, but when i authenticate, it show two different dialog, i do not know why, can every body help me???????

1.the first app it show Authenticate Dialog:

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/do7xm

2.The second app it show Authenticate Dialog:

[http://www.freeimagehosting.net/do7xm](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/xorio)

I want to change the second app to authenticate the same first app, but i do not know, you can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

LinkedIn recently [changed their authentication flow](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/making-it-easier-you-develop-linkedin), introducing the concept of granular user permissions.

The second dialog you are seeing is using this new flow, which is tied to the application key. Basically, the first application is using a key that was issued prior to August 7th, you will see the old authentication screen; for newer application keys, you will see the new permissions-based screen.

Comment: Thank you so much,Paul Mennega

Comment: You're welcome. Since you are new, if you feel this has answered your question, feel free to mark it as such - when you select answers to your questions, people are more likely to answer in the future.